# I used the vector, but I still have the issue of request for member push_back

Tags: c++, vector, compiler-errors

i used a vector, but this problem keeps happening

```
error: request for member 'push_back' in 'graph.std::vector<int>::operator[](((std:vector<int>::size_type)i))', which is of non-class type '_gnu_cxx::_alloc_traits<std::allocator<int>, int>:value_type' {aka 'int'}
```

How can I fix the problem

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
bool con=true;
vector<int> graph(1001);
int n,a,sum=1,i;
int find(int x){
    if(graph[x]==graph[graph[x]]){
        return sum;
    }
    sum++;
    find(graph[graph[x]]);
}
int main(){
    cin >>n;
    for(i=1; i<=n;i++){
        cin >> a;
        graph[i].push_back(a);
    }
    for(i=1; i<=n; i++){
        find(graph[i]);
    }

}
```

It's about searching for directional graphs using vectors
This code cannot proceed due to an error

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You're showing careless coding.   Not everything has a `push_back()` member function, and the compiler is telling you that `graph[i]` doesn't.   That's because `graph` is a `std::vector<int>` which means `graph[i]` is an element of that vector (and an `int`) and does not have a `push_back()` function   Presumably, you either intend to assign the `i`th element of `graph` to `a` (so do `graph[i]  = a`) or you made a mistake in defining `graph` to have `1001` elements, so need to initialise it with no elements (say, `vector<int> graph;`) and then append elements (say `graph.push_back(a);`).

Answer (score 0):

1. You seem to want to declare an empty vector instead of the size 1001:

   ```
    vector<int> graph;
   ```

   And insert elements like

   ```
    graph.push_back(a);
   ```

   `graph[i]` is `int` that is very clearly shown in the error.
2. Or maybe you wanted `vector<vector<int>> graph(1001);`

Also be careful with loops like `for(i=1; i<=n; i++)`, any good learning methiturals teach that array and vector indexes in C++ start with 0. Beginners should access vector elements like `graph.at(i)` instead of `graph[i]`.

Comment: Beginners must start with range-based `for` and `<ranges>`. This is safer and simpler when transitioning to/from python or other newer languages. Explicit indexing should be avoided as much as possible.